# How to return columnScope/RowScope through lambda in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know how can we return `Column/Row` through lamda function in jetpack compose. I tried something but it giving me error.

**PairContent**

```
@Composable
fun PairContent(
    bluetoothEnable: (ColumnScope) -> Unit,
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = true) {
        Scaffold {
            Column { columnScope ->
                bluetoothEnable(columnScope)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ColumnScope.() → Unit
Found:
ColumnScope.(Any?) → Unit

Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
```

**Error in image**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ColumnScope should be receiver of your parameter `bluetoothEnable: ColumnScope.() -> Unit`

```
@Composable
fun PairContent(
    bluetoothEnable:  @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = true) {
        Scaffold {
            Column {
                bluetoothEnable()
            }
        }
    }
}
```